# Spring Security / MVC / JPA --> Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I am having errors login from the HTML using Spring Security, Spring MVC and JPA.

This is my login.HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">>
    <title>Spring Framework Guru</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body class="security-app">
<div class="details">
    <h2>Spring Security - App</h2>
</div>

<form action="/login" method="post">

    <div class="lc-block">
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="style-4" name="username"
                   placeholder="User Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" class="style-4" name="password"
                   placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="button red small" />
        </div>
        <th:if test="${param.error ne null}">
            <div class="alert-danger">Invalid username and password.</div>
        </th:if>
        <th:if test="${param.logout ne null}">
            <div class="alert-normal">You have been logged out.</div>
        </th:if>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
           value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is WebSecurity class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .csrf();
}

@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

UserDetails service class:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository;

@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository, UserRolesRepository userRolesRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userRolesRepository = userRolesRepository;
}


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username);
    if (null == user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username: " + username);
    } else {
        List<String> userRoles = userRolesRepository.findRoleByUserName(username);
        return new CustomUserDetails(user, userRoles);
    }
}

}
```

I always have 405 error:

> 2016-10-16 12:15:30.710  WARN 2932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

Any ideas why is not calling the "configure(HttpSecurity http)". Am I missing something?

Thank you very much

Andres

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/xxx").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/xxx")
                .failureUrl("/xxx?error")
```

In addition

One typical reason in Spring MVC Applications for controller methods and pages not found is Spring's weird mapping convention to build URLs by adding a new link (or the form action="x") to the end of current URL. 'Request Method POST Not Supported' only means that your request is pointed to somewhere where nothing is accepting the POST request => URL mapping fails. On JSP sites you should always specify URLs like

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
```

or with JSTL

```
<c:url value="/login" var="loginUrl" />
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
```

Then you can be sure that your link is set right after the application root in URL. This will save you from a lot of unnecessary problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick repose @micaro, I have changed the form to <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"> and it find the post and query the DB. But my problem now is the return of the post: "http://localhost:8080/login?error". Does it mean than it could not retrieve the user details or they are not correct?

Comment: failureUrl is typically the same page as login page. By means of login?error you can add some kind of error message to the view if a user inputs a wrong username or password. failureUrl can just be login, if you don't want to add any message.

Comment: If you end up to failureUrl something went wrong with authentication. There are immense amount of reasons for that.